# How to create series of interactions for a regression model loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, regression

I am aiming to run each variable in the predictorlist vector by the first element of the interactionlist vector, then repeat the process for the second element of the interactionlist vector, and so on...

the current code (see below) only runs each model by each of the variables sequentially (i.e., the first element of the first list by the first element of the second list and so on.

How do I fix the code below for this purpose?! thanks!

```
predictorlist <- c(colnames(data_mvpa2)[3:9], "`Social norm`",colnames(data_mvpa2)[11])
interactionlist <- colnames(data_mvpa2)[c(12, 14:17,19:21)]

for (i in interactionlist){
  for (j in predictorlist) {
  factor=c(paste(i,j,sep=':'))
  model <- lmer(paste("MVPA_min_week ~
                      week + GENDER + AGEBAND + ETHNIC + SES + BMIBAND + OPSYS +
                      (1|ID) +", factor), data=data_mvpa2)
  print(summary(model))
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Check `update.formula()`. From a scientific/statistical point of view, your approach seems to introduce endless hidden overfit.

Comment: thanks... any hint on how I could apply in this case? Agree on the overfit POV

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```r
v <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")

for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in (i + 1):3) {
    inter <- paste0(". ~ . + ", v[i], ":", v[j])
    print(update.formula(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, inter))
  }
}

# y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x2
# y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x3
# y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x2:x3
```